# swapping engine considerations on BMW

Tags: engine, bmw

I have a bmw 530d from 2007 which requires a new engine.

It just so happens that I also own an old BMW 745i from 2002 which has an engine which works great. (The rest of the car being cosmetically challenged).

I want to investigate the feasibility of using the working engine of the 745i and bumping such into my 530d and would like some understanding of viability.

Comment: What are the engines? are the gearboxes both auto or manual? same number of gears? will the bell housing fit on the other engine if the gearbox is equivalent?

Comment: The 745i is an auto. The 530d a manual

Comment: Then that will be a challenge, anything is possible with a large enough wallet but may not be a smart thing to do - if you do then you will learn a lot! Done a couple of engine conversions and it's a lot of work...